# How to change access modifier of class in XML schema

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I am writing an XML schema file and I generate classes from it. The generated classes are always public. What I want is to have the classes package-visible only. Is this possible ? If yes, please give me a hint.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that JAXB *requires* the classes to be `public` - it won't work otherwise.

Comment: @skaffman - JAXB does not require that the classes are public.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - this sounds good. That means class visibility can be altered. Half of the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

When using wsimport, it's only possible to generate public classes. So your only option then is to search/replace in the generated files, if you want to make them package protected. However, depending on what you want to do with the generated classes, it may not make sense to make them package protected.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an XJC plug-in to accomplish this:

- http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/developPlugins.html